# Does anyone know this sequence of polynomials?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, polynomials, knot-theory, khovanov-homology, qa.quantum-algebra

A referee on a paper of mine showed me the following recurrence for polynomials $P_{n,k}\in\mathbb Q[q,q^{-1}]$ for $n\geq 0$ and $0\leq k\leq n/2$.
\begin{align}
P_{0,0}&=1\\
 \text{for $n\geq 1$}\quad P_{n,k}&=\begin{cases}
qP_{n-1,k-1}+q^{-1}P_{n-1,k}&2k+2\leq n\cr
 qP_{n-1,k-1}+\frac 12(1+q^{-1})P_{n-1,k}&2k+1=n\cr
 2P_{n-1,k-1}&2k=n
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where we interpret $P_{n,k}$ as zero if $k<0$.  Note that we have $P_{n,k}(1)=\binom nk$, so these are some sort of deformed binomial coefficients.

> Do these polynomials have a name?  Has anyone come across them before?

My context for the polynomials is the following.  I calculated the $s$-filtration on the Lee homology of the torus links $T_{n,n}$ and formed their Poincar\'e polynomials.  The result is:
\begin{align}\sum_{i,j}d_{T_{1,1}}(i,j)\cdot t^iq^j&=q+q^{-1}\cr\sum_{i,j}d_{T_{2,2}}(i,j)\cdot t^iq^j&=[1+q^2]+(tq^3)^2[q^{-2}+1]\cr\sum_{i,j}d_{T_{3,3}}(i,j)\cdot t^iq^j&=[q^3+q^5]+(tq^3)^4[q^{-3}+3q^{-1}+2q]\cr\sum_{i,j}d_{T_{4,4}}(i,j)\cdot t^iq^j&=[q^8+q^{10}]+(tq^3)^6[q^{-2}+4+3q^2]+(tq^3)^8[q^{-4}+3q^{-2}+2]\cr\sum_{i,j}d_{T_{5,5}}(i,j)\cdot t^iq^j&=[q^{15}+q^{17}]+(tq^3)^8[q+5q^3+4q^5]+(tq^3)^{12}[q^{-5}+5q^{-3}+9q^{-1}+5q]\cr\sum_{i,j}d_{T_{6.6}}(i,j)\cdot t^iq^j&=[q^{24}+q^{26}]+(tq^3)^{10}[q^6+6q^8+5q^{10}]\cr&+(tq^3)^{16}[q^{-4}+6q^{-2}+14+9q^2]+(tq^3)^{18}[q^{-6}+5q^{-4}+9q^{-2}+5]\end{align}
The above looked like a mess to me, and I figured there was no pattern, but the referee on my paper pointed out the that:
$$\sum_{i,j}d_{T_{n,n}}(i,j)\cdot t^iq^j=\sum_{k=0}^n(tq^3)^{2k(n-k)}q^{(n-2k)^2}P_{n,\min(k,n-k)}(q^2)$$
where $P_{n,k}$ is defined by the recurrence above!

Comment: uh what a coincidence, I've seen that very sequence in a paper I've recently refereed.

Comment: just kidding :)

Comment: A paper by Anonymous?

Comment: There is an inconsistency between the value at 1 (claimed to be a binomial coefficient) and the last formula, as illustrated in the examples, which seems to imply that the value at 1 is twice a binomial coefficient. Maybe there is a factor $1-q^2$ missing in the last formula ?

Comment: Dear F.C.,  I think this is due to the "folding" in the last sum, which I admit is slightly confusing.  The terms in the sum corresponding to $k$ and $n-k$ have the same leading power of $tq^3$, so I have combined them when listing the polynomials for $T_{n,n}$ above.  As you have noticed, the values of the $q$-polynomials in brackets at $q=1$ are: (2),(2,2),(2,6),(2,8,6),(2,10,20),(2,12,30,20) [these are the lines of the big list of Poincare polynomials], which agrees with pascal's triangle if we "fold every row in half and add terms".  This is why things look doubled.

Comment: If the formula still looks wrong, please let me know!

Comment: Have you tried typing the sequence of coefficients into Sloane's?

Comment: In case anyone cares: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1107.4702.pdf